# Azure App Service Authentication with Active Directory

Tags: azure, authentication, .net-core, azure-web-app-service

I have a dotnet core api in an app service on Azure.
When I run this locally, with authentication switched on, I can generate a bearer token and use that to successfully access the end points.

On azure, when authentication is switched off I can access the end points, but when I switch authentication on in azure, I can't access any end points with a token. Postman is just returning the standard response "The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred".

I can't see anything in application insights so I'm really in the dark.

Hoping someone will know of any common issues that could be behind this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access your web app **authenticated with Azure AD** using **B2C token**.

On local, created web app using Visual Studio only have three authentication choices:
[image]
As we can see, using Individual User Account is connecting to an Azure AD B2C account.

On portal, you could configure your app service with choices below:
[image]
If you are using Log in with Azure Active Directory, you should concern it is not same as B2C. Follow this page to [configure Azure AD authentication with web app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-aad).

## Get the AAD bear token:

1. Navigate to the app registrations page in your Azure Active Directory, choose the one you created in configuring authentication step. You would see the information like this:
   [image]
2. Go to `Certificates & secrets` page to create a secret, and copy that value, cause you would not see it after leave this page.
   [image]
3. Open Postman to get the access token, here is the required parameters:
   [image]
   [image]
   [image]
4. Use the bear token you got from last step to access your web app:
   [image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply!

Everything you describe in your response is exactly the way I have things configured.
I can generate a bearer token but when I try to use it I get the error that I described in my post

Comment: Actually internal server error might have many reasons. Sometimes it is a short downtime on server side, some times it is caused by your web app damage.You could try create a new web app and test again. If problem still exists, please raise a support on portal. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request

Comment: If my reply is helpful, please accept it as answer(click on the mark option beside the reply to toggle it from greyed out to fill in.), see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work